# How can I convert a fraction expression into a character vector in R?

Tags: r, vector, character, expression

Hello an thanks for the help.

I want to convert the expression: x / y (e.g. 1298 / 1109) into a character vector: "x / y" (e.g. "1298 / 1109") using R.

I have tried it with as.character(x/y) and with as.character.Date(x/y) but this only turns the result of the fraction into a character vector.

Comment: try `paste` or `glue::glue`

Comment: Try `paste(x, y, sep = "/")`

Comment: What sort of input do you have?  `as.character(expression(1298 / 1109))` works fine.  If you have the numbers in variables, @AllanCameron's solution is best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
> deparse(quote(1298 / 1109))
[1] "1298/1109"
```

or

```
> f <- function(x) deparse(substitute(x))

> f(1298 / 1109)
[1] "1298/1109"
```

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, you are right! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution using `paste`, as mentioned by Allan in the comments, wrapped in a function. Not as flexible as the solution by Tomas, but simple.

```r
f <- function(x,y) {
  paste(x, y, sep = " / ")
}

f(1298, 1109)

[1] "1298 / 1109"
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the excellent answers already given, in case that one wants to be able to evaluate the expression at some point you can take this approach.

```
x <- 1298
y <- 1109

z <- as.expression(substitute(x / y, list(x = x, y = y)))

z
# expression(1298/1109)

class(z)
# [1] "expression"

eval(z)
# [1] 1.1704

as.character(z)
# [1] "1298/1109"
```

Or without making it an `expression`

```
t <- substitute(x / y, list(x = x, y = y))

t
# 1298/1109 # not a string, but a "call"

class(t)
# [1] "call"

eval(t)
# [1] 1.1704

deparse(t)
# [1] "1298/1109"
```

Answer (score 0):

With `MASS`, there is `fractions` function

```
 MASS::fractions(1298/1109)
[1] 1298/1109
```